# Upgrading from free developer account to paid one

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm having a free Apple developer account, and I'm installing the apps I write on my own device. So, I'm actually limited to 3 different apps and they are usable for about one weeek, then I need to rebuild them.

My question is: if I buy one year of a paid developer account, what will be the result for me?

- Will I be able to build and install as much apps as I want?
- I assume that my apps on my device will last for longer (even if I don't publish them on the App Store), but how long? The year of my paid account, or as long as they work on my device/system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to install as many apps as you want on your device.

The expiration limit for applications developed with a paid account is **the validity of the provisioning profile**. It's maximum lifetime is 1 year.

Comment: Are you sure?  I have developer builds active on my device for months at a time without using TestFlight.

Comment: @Paulw11 You are right, my information was false. I updated my answer.

Comment: So, is it possible to extend the validity by publishing my software and 'buying' it? I think this could work, because I never saw an  App that suddently didn't work , and I have some apps that aren't 64 bits, so there may be some developers that didn't renew their account, I think...

Comment: AFAIK, when expired, it will work for those user who already have it, but won't be available anymore in the Store to download.